# Gmail API Error: Request payload size exceeds the limit: 1048576 bytes

Tags: android, gmail-api

I been using Gmail API in my app and it was working fine untill yesterday, now I'm getting

```
V/Error: 400 Bad Request
 {
   "code" : 400,
   "errors" : [ {
     "domain" : "global",
     "message" : "Request payload size exceeds the limit: 1048576 bytes.",
     "reason" : "badRequest"
   } ],
   "message" : "Request payload size exceeds the limit: 1048576 bytes.",
   "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
 }
```

I'm using multipart to attach the file, Here is the snippet of the code

```
MimeMessage createEmailWithAttachment(String to,
                                           String from,
                                           String subject,
                                           String bodyText,
                                           File file)
            throws MessagingException, IOException {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

    MimeMessage email = new MimeMessage(session);

    email.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    email.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO,
            new InternetAddress(to));
    email.setSubject(subject);

    MimeBodyPart mimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    mimeBodyPart.setContent(bodyText, "text/plain");

    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    multipart.addBodyPart(mimeBodyPart);

    mimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);

    mimeBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    mimeBodyPart.setFileName(file.getName());

    multipart.addBodyPart(mimeBodyPart);
    email.setContent(multipart);

    return email;
}
```

it was working perfectly few days back and now I get the above error whenever I try to send file larger than 1 MB, what could be work around for this?

Thanks

Comment: Odd that this problem just happened without a change in the code. Have you had a look at the [multipart upload](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads#multipart)? Allows a much bigger message size.

Comment: I retried one of old perfectly working sample and it is also giving the same issue now, I know for sure that it used to work perfectly okay!

Answer (score 0):

You can make upload requests in any of the following ways. Specify the method you are using with the uploadType request parameter.

Simple upload: **uploadType=media**. For quick transfer of smaller files, for example, `5 MB` or less.

Multipart upload: **uploadType=multipart**. For quick transfer of smaller files and metadata; transfers the file along with metadata that describes it, all in a single request.

Resumable upload: **uploadType=resumable**. For reliable transfer, especially important with larger files. With this method, you use a session initiating request, which optionally can include metadata. This is a good strategy to use for most applications, since it also works for smaller files at the cost of one additional HTTP request per upload.
Since you want to send data > 5 MB, use the multipart or resumable option.

```
public static MimeMessage createEmailWithAttachment(String to,
                                                        String from,
                                                        String subject,
                                                        String bodyText,
                                                        File file) throws MessagingException, IOException {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

        MimeMessage email = new MimeMessage(session);

        email.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        email.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO,
                new InternetAddress(to));
        email.setSubject(subject);

        MimeBodyPart mimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        mimeBodyPart.setContent(bodyText, "text/plain");

        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(mimeBodyPart);

        mimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);

        mimeBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        mimeBodyPart.setFileName(file.getName());

        multipart.addBodyPart(mimeBodyPart);
        email.setContent(multipart);

        return email;
    }
```

Check the documentation for more information: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue. In my case, I was unable to create a Draft larger than 1 MB, despite the Gmail documentation stating that the limit is 35 MB.

After some testing, I found that the issue is a bug specific to the .NET client library for the Gmail API. My workaround was to write my own code to call the Gmail API, bypassing the .NET client library. I've posted my solution here: http://www.gmass.co/blog/call-the-gmail-api-in-net-without-using-client-library/